# Activar Check de un datagridview conforme a un List

Tags: c#, sql-server

lo que quiero hacer es activar los checkbox de un datagriview conforme a un listado(List) que tengo ejemplo si un campo es "Si" entonces se activara el checkbox asi sucesivamente intente con este pero no me funciono si tienen alguna sugerencia favor de indicar se agradece cualquiera comentario

Tengo primero ese List que se saca de un Select

```
 public Int32 acmId { get; set; }
    public Int32 acmIdEmpresa { get; set; }
    public Int32 acmIdModulo { get; set; }
    public Int32 acmdIdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string acmVisualizacion { get; set; }
    public string acmRegistro { get; set; }
    public string acmActualizacion { get; set; }
    public string acmEliminacion { get; set; }
    public string acmUserCreate { get; set; }
    public DateTime acmDateCreate { get; set; }
    public string acmUserUpdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime acmDateUpdate { get; set; }
```

Tengo primero ese List que se almacenara para pasarlo al Datagridview

```
    public Int32 acmId { get; set; }
    public Int32 acmIdEmpresa { get; set; }
    public Int32 acmIdModulo { get; set; }
    public Int32 acmdIdUsuario { get; set; }
    public bool Ver { get; set; }
    public bool Reg { get; set; }
    public bool Act { get; set; }
    public bool Eli { get; set; }
```

intente pasar de un List a otro pero con valores bool y si reconoce el campo agregar el valor

```
    public List<CheckPrueba> lstCheckPrueba = new List<CheckPrueba>();

 List<AccesoModulos> LstClientes = null;
            AccesoModulos ObjClientes = null;
            IBAccesoModulos ObjClientesb = null;

            try
            {
                LstClientes = new List<AccesoModulos>();
                ObjClientes = new AccesoModulos();
                ObjClientes.acmdIdUsuario = ID;
                LstClientes = ObjClientesb.FP_LISTAR_AccesoModulos(ObjClientes).ToList();

                CheckPrueba objCheckPrueba = null;
                objCheckPrueba = new CheckPrueba();


                foreach (var a in LstClientes)
                {
                    objCheckPrueba.acmId = a.acmId;
                    objCheckPrueba.acmIdEmpresa = a.acmIdEmpresa;
                    objCheckPrueba.acmIdModulo = a.acmIdModulo;
                    objCheckPrueba.acmdIdUsuario = a.acmdIdUsuario;

                    bool IscheckedVer = a.acmVisualizacion == "SI";
                    if (IscheckedVer == true)
                    {
                        objCheckPrueba.Ver = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objCheckPrueba.Ver = false;

                    }

                    bool IscheckedReg = a.acmRegistro == "SI";
                    if (IscheckedReg == true)
                    {
                        objCheckPrueba.Reg = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objCheckPrueba.Reg = false;

                    }

                    bool IscheckedAct = a.acmActualizacion == "SI";
                    if (IscheckedAct == true)
                    {
                        objCheckPrueba.Reg = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objCheckPrueba.Reg = false;

                    }
                    bool IscheckedEli = a.acmEliminacion == "SI";
                    if (IscheckedEli == true)
                    {
                        objCheckPrueba.Eli = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objCheckPrueba.Eli = false;

                    }
                    lstCheckPrueba.Add(objCheckPrueba);

                    datalistado.DataSource = lstCheckPrueba;
            }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Mostrar_Mensaje_Error(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema parece ser que el texto de a.acmRegistro esta en minúscula y lo estas comparando con uno en mayúscula, podrias solucionarlo de esta manera

```
             foreach(var a in LstClientes){
                if (a.acmVisualizacion.ToUpper() == "SI")
                {
                    objCheckPrueba.Ver = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    objCheckPrueba.Ver = false;
                }
              }
```

O de esta otra manera.

```
           foreach(var a in LstClientes){

            objCheckPrueba.Ver = (a.acmVisualizacion.ToUpper() == "SI")? true:false; 

            }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo me ayudo